# consistent hashing where you want a key mapped to multiple servers

Tags: high-availability, consistent-hashing

I'm wondering if I'm missing a concept here somewhere, and wondering if someone can explain how this might work.

My understanding of consistent hashing makes perfect sense where I want to map a particular key to one server.  I can just map the key to a single server or virtual node clockwise or counterclockwise from the key.

How does consistent hashing work if I want to specify that each key should be mapped to some quorum of servers I define?  For example, what if I have 5 servers and want each key mapped on at least two servers?  Would I just choose the two unique servers clockwise on the ring, or is there some other strategy you need?  Could you equivalently choose one server clockwise and one counterclockwise?  What if you want a key mapped to an arbitrary number of servers?

My issue may be also that I just don't know the right terminology to search for.  My particular use case is that I want to have a cluster of Prometheus collectors, say 7, and say I have a pool of 150 exporters.  I want each exporter to be collected by at least 3 of the collectors.  What's a good way to think about this problem?  Appreciate thoughts, thanks!

Comment: If you want sharding scrape targets among a set of Prometheus instances and scraping every target by a fixed number of Prometheus instances, then take a look at  [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#scraping-big-number-of-targets) for `vmagent`, which supports this feature out of the box. `vmagent` is a Prometheus-like metrics collector I work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that consistent hashing is actually a special case of [rendezvous hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing), which is what I was looking for.